# Initializing external service connections in Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing a Dataflow streaming pipeline. In one of the transformations, DoFn I want to access an external service - in this case, it is Datastore.

Is there any best practice for this sort of initialization step? I don't want to create the datastore connection object for every processElement method call.

Answer (score 5):

In the Dataflow SDK, the simplest thing you can do is add a check to initialize you external service in your first element:

```
class DatastoreCallingDoFn extends DoFn {

    private ExtServiceHandle handle = null;

    private ExtServiceHandle initializeConnection() {
      // ...
    }

    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      // ... process each element -- setup will have been called
      if (handle == null) {
        handle = initializeConnection();
      }
      // Process elements
    }
}
```

---

If you are using Beam, you can use the `@Setup` decorator to decorate a function in your `DoFn` to do the setup of your DoFn, such as initializing the datastore connection.

```
class DatastoreCallingDoFn extends DoFn {
    @Setup
    public void initializeDatastoreConnection() {
      // ...
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        // ... process each element -- setup will have been called
    }
}
```

This is similar to the [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646447/singleton-in-google-dataflow/44657261#44657261).

Comment: Its streaming pipeline ,so setup method will be called for every element., and I didn't find the `Setup` or `ProcessElement` annotations in standard dataflow dependency.

Comment: I'm sorry. `@Setup` and `ProcessElement` are part of the Beam library. I got confused. Though `@Setup` is not called per-element. It's called per-DoFn instance. I'll edit the question to consider both options.