# ApacheBeam/DataFlow runner with JdbcIO writer creates too many connections

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-sql, apache-beam

I'm using GCP cloud SQL, with MySQL instance and using JdbcIo to write data from DataFlow pipeline to MySQL.

Seems like DataFlow generates too many connections, and reach the DB limit (4000), even that I specify in the connection pool, max size: 1000

```java
 ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
 try {
       dataSource.setDriverClass("org.mysql.Driver");
     } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed set mysql driver",e);
     }
       dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://google/live-data?cloudSqlInstance<INSTANCE_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&user=<USER>&password=<PASSWORD>");

       dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
       dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(1000);
```

Also, in the dashboard I can see much more connections then queries:
[image]

[image]

[image]

my pom.xml

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> DataFlow generates too many connections, and reach the DB limit (4000), even that I specify in the connection pool, max size: 1000

A quick guess would be that since Dataflow can have multiple runners, each runner likely has its own connection pool. This means that each pool will have a 1000 separate connections. This is highly likely way more connections than you should actually be using - see HikariCP's wiki on [pool sizing](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

> Also, in the dashboard I can see much more connections then queries:

Since you set `setInitialPoolSize(1000)` the pool doesn't lazily establish connections as needed, and instead it creates 1000 on initialization of the pool. From the sample provided, you haven't provided any limits on connection lifespans, so these connections will likely persist as long as possible.

Comment: Yes, seems like this was because of many instances of the connection pool. I reduce the number of allowed connections to 10, and then each DataFlow worker create its own connection pool and the total sum of all instances is still lower.

Comment: I also make one instance of connection pool per worker, before, I initialized the connection pool per ParDo function, in the @SetUp method. I changed it to be initialized once per worker (singleton)

Comment: Hello Branchi, I came across with the same necessity;however, I  couldn’t figured out how to initialize the instance once. Can you help me? I can’t have to many database connections open in my pipeline, I would like, if possible, to open one connection and share it. Thank you

Comment: Hi @JulianoMedeiros, this will be a long comment, I wrote some Medium post on how to do it, in that post it is with RedisClient but the concept is the same, how to init client/pool only once and use it in all the functions in the pipeline. please read it, if you still have question I'll be glad to help and share code snippets .https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/apache-beam-a-minor-tip-for-cleaner-code-f293df3e3372

Comment: Hi @Brachi ,do you have something in python ? I'm trying to use your idea; however, my pipeline is written in python

Comment: no, sorry, i'm less familiar with python...

Comment: @JulianoMedeiros I'm not super familiar with Dataflow, but this sounds like the pattern you might need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646447/singleton-in-google-dataflow