# BigQuery Storage WRITE API: Concurrent connections per project for small regions per region

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using BigQuery Storage WRITE api to load the data to BigQuery. This is used in a `Dataflow` job run in a `batch` mode.

I noticed on particular day when we were loading large volumes of data, we exceeded the default value `1000` quota for 'Concurrent connections per project for small regions per region'.

Looking in the monitoring in API/Service details, I can the `peak usage` ( see screenshot ) which confirms the quota exceed issue.

My question is:

Is there are out of the box monitoring metric that gives away the Dataflow JOB ID that consumed so many connections?

I have checked the `Dataflow` metrics and `BigQuery` monitoring, I did not get any metrics that will give me the name of Job that created so many connections.

In particular, I have tried the steps given here

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#view_quota_usage_and_limits

but for me I can't see the any of the metric below for selection in the limit value

`ConcurrentWriteConnectionsPerProject`, `ConcurrentWriteConnectionsPerProjectEU`, and `ConcurrentWriteConnectionsPerProjectRegion`

Any pointers will be useful.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Bihag Kashikar,  dataflow beam runners can generate too many [connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56008024/17258510). Have you checked logs for the ID?

Comment: @kiranmathew yes, trying that too, thing is we have about 13 jobs running all with different volume of data and to go through logs is tedious, hence why I was looking for metrics